# Refresh content page when master page is updated

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

My site uses a Calendar control to determine what date to get data for.
Because this calendar should be visible on every page, I've placed it on my MasterPage.

If the date on the calendar is changed, it should cause the data shown in the Content page to be updated with data specific for the new date. Essentially, it should cause the page to be reloaded.

Because the calendar is on the MasterPage, that's where I'm putting the SelectionChanged event handler, but I'm not sure how to "reload" the content page from here. All I can think of is a Response.Redirect, and I'm not sure if that's the best option.

Can anyone give me any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Decided I'd simplify this and make the master page element a hyperlink that redirected to a page that had the calender on it and "Save" button on it.

I found this much easier to manage...

The calendar loads with today's date, allows the user to select another date and the save button writes the new selected date into a session variable read for the data that is to appear on all the content pages.

It means the user has to specially go away from what he/she is currently doing in order to set the date, but I actually prefer it this way.